# how correctly update this cordova plugin? (execute() CallbackContext PluginResult)

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I'm trying to update a not-yet updated plugin (AdMob) found on github

https://github.com/rajpara11/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/AdMobPlugin/AdMobPlugin.java

relevant code is that, which works, but needs some fixes:

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray inputs, CallbackContext callbackContext)
{
    PluginResult result = null;

    if (ACTION_CREATE_BANNER_VIEW.equals(action)) {
        result = this.executeCreateBannerView(inputs);
    } else if (ACTION_REQUEST_AD.equals(action)) {
        result = executeRequestAd(inputs);
    } else {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, String.format("Invalid action passed: %s", action));
        callbackContext.error(String.format("Invalid action passed: %s", action));
    }

    // ...

}
```

what I need to add is a check of the `result` variable, i was thinking to do something like this

```
if(result == PluginResult.Status.OK)
{
    callbackContext.success();
    return true;
}
return false;
```

but of course it won't work... how can I update that correctly? Documentation didn't help,

and my Java is not ninja enough :(

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I have seen this done in the core plugins is to have a private CallbackContext variable at the start of your class, then in your execute(), set `this.callbackContext = callbackContext`  Now you can use the execute() method to compare the value of the action string and delegate out to your private methods. In these methods you will do callbackContext.sendPluginResult(...). You return true or false in execute() based on if the action was valid or not.

So I think it should look something like:

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray inputs, CallbackContext callbackContext)
{
    this.callbackContext = callbackContext;

    if (ACTION_CREATE_BANNER_VIEW.equals(action)) {
       this.executeCreateBannerView(inputs);
       return true;    // return true because this is a valid action
    } else if (ACTION_REQUEST_AD.equals(action)) {
        executeRequestAd(inputs);
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, String.format("Invalid action passed: %s", action));
        return false;
        // could possibly do the following to send NO_RESULT:
        // callbackContext.sendPluginResult(newPluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT));
    }
}
```

and then later:

```
private void executeCreateBannerView(inputs){
    //after doing all of your work:
    callbackContext.success();
    // or callbackContext.sendPluginResult() to pass data back 

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer! i was looking at the latest phonegap/cordova plugins... seems that PluginResult class isn't actually used anymore... in your opinion should i update the admob plugin removing that? thanks

Comment: Hello, you're welcome. The PluginResult class is still used, but we just use it in a different way now. (It looks like most of the plugins in the github phonegap-plugins repo are pretty old and haven't been updated at all.) Now we pass the PluginResult to the CallbackContext class, which takes care of sending the result back to the JavaScript. And yes, you should upgrade  your code because the Plugin class that admob plugin is using will be removed in Cordova 2.7: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2202?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel  Good luck!